# Any anchor elements have white text

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this exam where it wants me to make any anchor elements white text.
I have tried all I know, but doesn't seem to be accepting it. I have not found any help to try to uncover what it means, all it says when I check answers is did I make `<a>` color #FFFFFF

Any help on this would be appreciated

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(216, 27, 96, 0.6);
}

h2 {
  color: #FFCC00;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

h4 {
  color: #FFCC00;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 75vw;
}

.midground,
.foreground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15vh 0 0 15vw;
  padding: 0;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 59vh;
}

.midground {
  background-color: hsla(208, 79%, 51%, 0.4);
}

.foreground {
  background-color: hsla(45, 100%, 51%, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Please add some html that allows to reproduce the problem.  (When I add an `<a>` element to the snippet, its text appears white.)

Comment: Some other CSS must be overriding your `a{ color: #FFFFFF}` rule, or some of your links aren't using the `a` tag.   Right click on one of the anchor elements that isn't white, and choose "Inspect" or "inspect element" (depending on your browser).  You'll be able to see all the CSS properties that are affecting that element, and where they came from.

Comment: (You may need to enable developer tools in your browser to be able to inspect elements.  This, too, will depend on which browser you're using, but should be easy enough to find instructions for your specific browser)

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be that your other CSS code overrides the `color: #ffffff;`. This can be fixed by increasing the rule importancy:

```css
a {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

---

Also, you should set styles for specific states, too. I listed here the most important states:

### `:hover`

This applies when user hovers mouse cursor over the link.

```css
a:hover {
  color: #efefef !important;
}
```

### `:active`

This applies when user clicks the link.

```css
a:active {
  color: #eee !important;
}
```

### `:visited`

This applies after user visited the link in close history instead of normal style.

```css
a:visited {
  color: #fff !important; /* Disabling the behavior by setting the same value as the main style */
}
```

---

**Note:** If you find out that something works without the `!important`, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just `a` as a selector for your css rule you should use `a:link`, and you might also want to combine that with `a:visited`, so the link stays the same way after it has been visited for the first time by a user. So the complete rule would be:

```
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Full example:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(216, 27, 96, 0.6);
}

a:link, a:visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">some link text</a>
```